# Trigger child element's onclick event, but not parent's

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, event-propagation

I've got some nested elements, each with an onclick event. In most cases, I want both events to fire when the user clicks the child (both parent and child events are triggered - default behavior). However, there is at least one case where I want to trigger the child's onclick event (from javascript, not a user's click), but not the parent's. How can I prevent this from triggering the parent event?

[image]

What I was is:

**User clicks A:** A's onclick fires.
**User clicks B:** B's onclick fires, A's onclick also fires
**Manually trigger B's click:** B fires, A does not (this one is the problem)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`triggerHandler`](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/) on the child; this will not let the event propagate through the DOM:

> Events created with .triggerHandler() do not bubble up the DOM
>   hierarchy; if they are not handled by the target element directly,
>   they do nothing.

Comment: Exactly what I needed! I'm kinda surprised it didn't come up in any of my searches.

Comment: .triggerHandler('click') does not work in safari. Any work around for safari?

Comment: @Shab you can use [stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/). see my answer

Answer (score 4):

### Method 1:

You can use  [`stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) method to prevent event bubbling.

```
$('.element').on('click', function(e){
e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Check out this[`DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/5as880n8/1/)

### Method 2:

You can use  `return false` to prevent event bubbling and this will also prevent the default action.

```
$('.element').on('click', function(e){
//--do your stuff----
return false;
});
```