# Execute js function when a specific item is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

Please tell me how I can execute the `go2` function when I click on the button without executing the `go` function

```js
function go($i) {
  alert($i);
}
function go2($i) {
  alert($i);
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #eaeaea;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="go('159');">
<button onclick="go2('160');">Go 2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trigger child element's onclick event, but not parent's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20505143/trigger-child-elements-onclick-event-but-not-parents)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to use event.stopPropagation()

```js
function go($i) {
  alert($i);
}
function go2($i) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  alert($i);
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #eaeaea;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="go('159');">
<button onclick="go2('160');">Go 2</button>
</div>
```